# mount /var as tmpfs && backup to disk @ shutdown && restore from disk @ boot

Tags: linux, fedora, tmpfs, var

I run a fedora 27 server mainly for an email service, that is mainly used for temporary email  communications by a software. Almost nothing permanent need to be stored on the /var, maybe except it's still good to keep the /var/log..

I know fedora already using tmpfs for /tmp which is great! I want to further conserve my HDD by putting the /var on tmpfs too!.. But also would like to keep the /var data somewhere on the disk.

So I'd like to be able mount the /var as tmpfs - just like the /tmp is already now - but be able to also backup the /var to the disk somewhere at shutdown (or maybe even better if can backup at certain time interval), and also restore the /var from disk at boot up.

Has anybody already done this? Can you please share how this can be done?

Comment: How would you deal with a power outage?

Comment: Welcome to this site! You say "Almost nothing permanent need to be stored on the /var", are you sure? Any MySQL  (or Postgre, or...) databases? The **mail queue** is _usually_ kept in `/var`. That said, `rsync` is probably the best tool to sync your `/var` to a backup location.

Comment: Placing /var in tmpfs is a terrible idea.  Far better to identify the oft-changing files that are worrying you and ensure they alone are placed in tmpfs.

Comment: Hopefully UPS is good enough for power outage..?

Comment: @shunz appreciate the tip :-)

Comment: steve thanks for comments. 
the mail server is used by a software for temp purpose, so the main thought was to put the /var/mail on tmpfs. Also these days servers got probed so much, it's probably good to put /var/log on tmpfs too.. 
I read someone asked about putting /var/log on tmpfs earlier, and there were comment about timing with mounting the /var.. so wonder if there'd be issue mounting sub-dir under the /var separate from /var?.. Or is it better off just putting the entire /var on one tmpfs? 
If this is done, does HDD ever get a chance to spin down under f27 anyway? 
thanks.

Comment: If you intend to keep the contents of `/var` on disk, might I suggest you put them in `/var`? In other words, the system is already doing what you want, just much more effectively than with tmpfs.

Comment: @Michael 
The reason for me is to try something for keeping the HDD life a little longer. cause the server 's getting about a million probes a day, lots of writing to the disk /w the log.. + I also use the /var/mail in high frequency due to the special software related role..

Comment: Maybe you should just use all your free memory as a disk cache, to minimize writes... but Linux already does this! If you are so worried about your hard drive dying, why don't you just replace it now?

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper into the question, and learning more from the feedbacks, I think Michael is right.. Seems Fedora has already taken care of this indeed..

```
journald.conf 
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
```

So this seems to mean the logs will only commit to disk after every 5m correct?

And if so, then the HDD situation is not so terrible as I thought afterall..? All those disk-writes showing on the graph probably to mean writing to the cache then.. Would this be correct?

For the `/var/mail` or `/var/spool/mail` I think I'll mount it on another partition and add `commit=600,noatime` which should be good enough.